# Fixar URL dos SRC pelo HTACCESS

Tags: htaccess, querystring

Eu estou usando URL amigavel via HTACCESS e porque estou usando isso as páginas perder o styles e js. Por causa que o caminho (URL) é feito como ex /categoria/pizza então ele procura src="categoria/pizza/style.css" . Teria alguma forma de fixar a URL base pelo HTACCESS?

Comment: Aguardamos um retorno sobre as respostas já dadas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Minha recomendação é você especificar sempre o caminho absoluto do arquivo, já que o PHP interpreta com base no caminho do servidor e os `src` e `href` em relação ao caminho do navegador... nesses casos você teria que criar uma variável ou uma constante para resolver essa diferença

```
$UrlSite = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,trim(parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_PATH), '/\\'));
$DirSite = explode(DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR,__DIR__);
if(in_array($UrlSite[0], $DirSite) AND $UrlSite[0] != ''){
   $Directory = "/$UrlSite[0]/";
   //é atribuido ao smarty {$Directory} no arquivo de configuração do smarty
}else{
   $Directory = "/";
}
```

Na variável acima eu comparo o caminho do servidor com o caminho do navegador, se a pasta fora a mesma nos 2, ele grava na variável... então nos `src` e `href` coloco a variável sempre na frente do caminho absoluto. Ex:

> <a href="{$Directory}imagens/imprensa/large/imagem.jpg">

Sendo que aqui a pasta `imagens` está na raiz do meu projeto

Agora algo que considero muito importante, por que não usar a tag `<base>`?
Simples, pois ela não tem compatibilidade com navegadores antigos, IE9 ou anteriores continuarão sem encontrar seus arquivos ou seja, você teria de deixar de dar suporte para essas versões...

Meu htaccess está da seguinte forma

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   Options -Indexes
   ErrorDocument 404 /Errors/404.html
   ErrorDocument 403 /Errors/403.html
   RewriteRule ^/?$ page/php/Home.php
</IfModule>
```

A principio essa foi a melhor solução que encontrei, pelo menos foi a unica compatível com todas as necessidades e com todos os navegadores... não encontrei nenhuma forma de fazer isso diretamente pelo .htaccess

Answer (score 0):

Neste caso o ideal é você especificar o caminho dos arquivos para a) URL completa ou b) caminho relativo (ex: "/style.css" ou "/css/style.css"). Este problema nào está relacionado com o htaccess

Comment: Não teria alguma forma de indicar a URL pelo HTACCESS?

Comment: Se você possui um número limitado de arquivos, seria possível, no entanto você perde flexibilidade com isso. A forma recomendada é realizar o ajuste para buscar o arquivo no caminho correto.

Answer (score 0):

Uma alternativa é definir a tag `<base>` no cabeçalho das páginas HTML.

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp

Também defina no httaccess a exceção de regra de reescrita para quando encontrar uma pasta ou arquivo, tal com a base onde a regra será aplicada.

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
```